# Creating a list of triples from a list of pairs such that all subset of triples is present in the list of pairs

Tags: scala, list, function, apache-spark

I'm new to scala/spark and not sure of functional programming while writing spark programs.

I have an rdd of the following format:

```
//user_freq_pair : (1,List((98,101), (98,100), (98,102), (100,101), (101,102)))
scala> user_freq_pair
res17: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, List[(Int, Int)])]
```

I want to calculate a new list of triples from the doubles but the list of triples should have all it's subsets present in the original list from which we are calculating. So we can't simply flatten the pair list and then generate all triples.

In the example above we will have only the following triple from the four triples possible(If we flatten out we have `(1,List(98,100,101,102)`.No. of ways to choose 3 from 4 is 4 ways):

```
//user_triple: (1,List((98,100,101)) because (98,101),(98,100),(100,101) all three are present in the original list
scala> user_triple
res18: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, List[(Int, Int,Int)])]
```

I'm not sure how to write functions for RDD's and achieve the above challenge.

Comment: isn't List(98, 101, 102) also a valid Triplet ?

Comment: yes it is, thanks for pointing out

Comment: Instead of `List[List[Int]]` how to generate `List[(Int,Int,Int)]`

Comment: I have updated the answer to output List[(Int, Int, Int)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following functions would identify the candidate Triplets that qualify your condition.

```
def generateTriplets(input: List[(Int,Int)]) = {
    val combinations = input.flatMap({case (x,y) => List(x,y)}).toSet.toList.combinations(3).toList
    combinations collect { 
          case a::b::c::Nil if 
               (input.contains((a,b)) || input.contains((b,a))) &&
               (input.contains((b,c)) || input.contains((c,b))) &&
               (input.contains((a,c)) || input.contains((c,a))) => (a,b,c)

    }   
}
```

**sample input**

```
scala> generateTriplets(List((98,101), (98,100), (98,102), (100,101), (101,102)))
res37: List[List[Int]] = List(List(98, 101, 100), List(98, 101, 102))
```

you could then map over this function in your RDD to get the desired output.

Comment: Hi, If we have to do the same process but for a new list of triple pairs and then find a `combination(4)` and then again a list of 4pairs and then find `combination(5)` I have to define the function again and again. Is there a better way to implement so that I just pass the number, the List[(number pair)] and find the number+1 combinations